# How can we send and receive data in same HTML form using angularjs with JSON schema?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, jsonschema

Suppose this is the form:

```
<form name="inputForm">
 <input type="text" name="ipname" ng-model="formData.name">
 <input type="text" name="ipage" ng-model="formData.age">
 <button ng-submit="formSubmit(formData)"></button>
</form>
```

How do we need to write JSON schema with name or ng-model to store it in db?

Comment: What's your problem? You can send formDate as JSON and receive put in same object.

Comment: Do you mean how to parse formDate to json? How to write JSON schema from your ng-model?

Comment: Thanks @Jarek. The problem is I have a form of 3 inputs and inside that form an additional button when clicked dropdowns another 5 input rows. The whole input elements(3+5) are inside a single form. I need to get data for 1st form and post data for 2nd form(sometimes need not to post). And if that form is edited need to post the whole(3+5) input elements to db. Also i was wondering how the JSON schema for that form would be??

Comment: as per my understand,you need to send data from client to server once form is edited in the form of json,for this either you use angular.toJson to send json data to server or write code in server side to handle the client data.

Comment: Thanks @Basavaraj. The 2nd 5 input elements are array type with ng-repeat. So how to write the JSON schema for that?

Comment: It's pretty simple, i answer example for you. But why u need few forms, can't you put it in one?

Comment: The input elements are inside a single form.I have not used ng-form for nested forms. Its a simple html form, the 2nd 5 input elements are optional. Its user's choice. If user adds, then they need to saved, if not save the first 3.

Comment: @NoobOwl you can make object with key and value,so you can add key with array value and send that object as angular.toJson(obj). exapmle $scope.data['optvalue'] = angular.toJson($scope.policySetUpDate);

Comment: NoobOwl have you tried Angular Schema Form? It is more UI oriented than JSON Schema alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows. The only issue in your version was you were using [**`ng-submit`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) with button which should be used at `form` level.

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('testController',function($scope){
  $scope.formData = {}
  
  $scope.formSubmit = function() {
    // Form validations
    console.log($scope.formData)
    // Use formData JSON Object to send it to API using $http/$resource
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  <form name="inputForm">
    <input type="text" name="ipname" ng-model="formData.name">
    <input type="text" name="ipage" ng-model="formData.age">
    <button ng-click="formSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @tanmay. I will try this. Tell me about JSON schema, when writing the schema for REST, in JSON schema whether name or model name is written in schema properties to save to db OR if we need to call an API ??